# Getting text from webpage

Tags: text, applescript, extract

I asked and read different topic about this in the last month, but still didn't get it

I want to extract some data from a website using Applescript or something simular

With this script

```
to getInputByClass2(theClass, num) -- defines a function with two inputs, theClass and num
    tell application "Safari" --tells AS that we are going to use Safari
        set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1 -- uses JavaScript to set the variable input to the information we want
    end tell
    return input --tells the function to return the value of the variable input
end getInputByClass2


-- start here
getInputByClass2("field type-string field-accountname", 0)
set theText to Unicode text
set theText to getInputByClass2("field type-string field-accountname", 0)
```

I have this result :

```
"<div class=\"content\"><div class=\"related-orders-indicator component\" id=\"XXXX-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEE\" data-bad=\"0\" data-good=\"51\" data-total=\"51\">
    <label class=\"count\" style=\"display: block;\">51</label>
</div><label class=\"name\">accountname</label><span class=\"value\">1985</span><div class=\"confirmation\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"tri-state confirmation square-confirmation-style\"></div></div>"
```

How can I have only the account name as a variable, in this example 1985.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `text item delimiters`:

```
property leftEdge : "class=\"value\">"
property rightEdge : "</span>"

set theSource to "<div class=\"content\"><div class=\"related-orders-indicator component\" id=\"XXXX-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEE\" data-bad=\"0\" data-good=\"51\" data-total=\"51\"><label class=\"count\" style=\"display: block;\">51</label></div><label class=\"name\">accountname</label><span class=\"value\">1985</span><div class=\"confirmation\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"tri-state confirmation square-confirmation-style\"></div></div>"

set saveTID to text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to leftEdge
set classValue to text item 2 of theSource
set text item delimiters to rightEdge
set theResult to text item 1 of classValue
set text item delimiters to saveTID
theResult
```

Comment: Last thing, i'm doing that for an email address and have  <span>email@<a target="_blank" href="http://www.gmail.com">gmail.com</a> as a result? any easy wait to have a string version ?

Comment: You have to specify the (unique) actual characters left and right from the requested string as `leftEdge` and `rightEdge`

Comment: sorry, it's the same, "class=\"value\">"
property rightEdge : "</span>"

Comment: According your first comment it seems to be `</a>` on the right side and `href=\"gmail.com\">` on the left side. The difficulty that the `href` value is a variable. But if the `href` value is the same as the actual value you can filter between `href=\"` and `"\">"`

Comment: sorry, here is a another exemple because the first one is confusing  <span>kevin@<a target="_blank" href="http://www.163.com">163.com</a> Actualy I want the email address, but on the website, I try to extrat the text, the link of the email, is not a mailto but the URL of the domain of whatever the email address is, in this exemple http://www.163.com

Comment: Then you need two steps one  to extract `kevin@` and one for `163.com` and then concatenate the strings.

Comment: Ok got it, I have property leftEdge14 : "http://www."
property rightEdge14 : ">" for the domain the only issue is I have the correct address but in this format :  kevin@163.com" how can I get ride of the -"

Comment: Include the double quote in the right edge : `"\">"` (the backslash escapes the double quote for the ability to be represented in a literal string)